# differentiation, critical number and graph sketching

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Consider the graph of the function $$f(x) = x^2-x-12$$

(a) Find the equation of the secant line joining the points $(-2, -6)$ and $(4, 0)$.

(b) Use the Mean Value Theorem to determine a point c in the interval $(-2, 4)$ such
that the tangent line at c is parallel to the secant line.

(c) Find the equation of the tangent line through c.

(d) Sketch the graph of $f$, the secant line, and the tangent line on the same axes.

---

I used $m= \dfrac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$ to get the slope.

$$m =\frac{0-(-6)}{4-(-2)}=\dfrac66=1$$

or $m=\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ and it gave me $1$

then differentiating:

$$f'(x)= 2x-1=1 \leadsto 2x=1+1\leadsto 2x=2\leadsto x=1$$

Comment: No, don't just dump a bunch of questions here with no source, no motivation, and no indication you've put in any work beyond copy'n'paste. Tell us what you've done. Do you know what a secant line is? do you know how to find the equation of a line joining two given points? Help yourself a little, and someone will help you.

Comment: yes i have tried it, i just get it all mixed up. i got c=2 and my gradient was 1. i stumbled on the question while studying n i need help with it.

Comment: Edit your question to include everything you know about it, and then post to meta to ask for re-opening.

Comment: who is meta? n how do i go about it? i simply needed assistance, u don't have to give me the answer or get personal. i was doing some study against the future, we haven't touched this topic in school yet., so all i could do was find the slope, and the critical point

Comment: First, edit your question as suggested. Then look up at the top of this page, and click on "meta".

Comment: what do  i do after clicking on meta\

Comment: What I wrote: you post a question there, indicating what has happened here, and asking for the question here to be re-opened.

Comment: Please do not edit your post to add useless noise, like horizontal lines at the top of your post.

Comment: The statement of (b) doesn't really make sense.  The mean value theorem states that such a $c$ exists, but it is not used to find $c$.

Comment: i did not make up the question, i saw it. u dont have to help if u dont wanna. thank u

Comment: @precious, people here is trying to help you, so I think that your comment is a little bit unnecessary.

Comment: sorry for the comment. i was pretty tired that day. i really do appreciate your help everyone, you are the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Say the point $(x,y)$ is on the secant line between points $(-2,6)$, $(4,0)$. So the equation of the secant line will be
$$\frac{y-(-6)}{x-(-2)}=\frac{0-(-6)}{4-(-2)}\Rightarrow\frac{y+6}{x+2}=1\Rightarrow y=x-4$$
As you see the slope of the secant line is $1$.

b) If the tangent line is parallel to secant line then  the slope of tangent line at $c$ has same slope with secant line that is:
$$f'(c)=1\Rightarrow2c-1=1\Rightarrow c=1$$
Now if you substitute $c=1$ into $f$ you will find $f(c)=-12$. So the tanget line is tangent to $f$ at $(1,-12)$

c) The equation of tangent line at $(x_0,y_0)$ is $y-y_0=f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$. So the equation of tangent at $(1,-12)$ will be 
$$y-(-12)=f'(1)(x-1)\Rightarrow y+12=x-1\Rightarrow y=x-13$$

d) For plotting you can use [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x-13,x-4,x%5E2-x-12%20from%20x=-3%20to%206)

Comment: thanks guys, i understand the concept properly now.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

a) Remember that the equation of a line is $y=mx+r$, where $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$. If $(-2,6),(4,0)$ belongs to the secant line, then you can substitute these points in the equation to get a linear system.

b) As you have posted in your question, you alread know the answer for this item, however, I would like to note, as @JonasMeyer did, that the Mean Value Theorem is unnecessary.

c) Well, you know $m$ and know that $x=1$, then you can use the same equation as in the item a) to determine $r$.

d) ...